# Convert specific video and audio track only with ffmpeg by language

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, language

so for example if my video has 3 audio stream 1 english, 1 german, 1 lithuanian. And for each video it can be in random order how would I be able to convert the file and select only lithuanian language if I didn't know witch number is the lithuanian audio? So for one video lithuanian language would be third audio track and for the order it would be secound and so on (random).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-map` option:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:lit -c copy output
```

The first `-map` option selects the video stream(s). The second `-map` option selects all streams with Lithuanian language metadata. Note that it will select all streams, including video, audio, and subtitles labeled as Lithuanian, so you may get the same video stream(s) selected multiple times.